# Reactive filtering in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application where the filters here are reactive with respect to each other. Not sure there is some issue in the code. The values are not to be seen here. Can anyone help me here?

Is there any alternate way?

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets) ## for picker input
library(shinydashboard) 
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(xtable)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(sparkline)
library(data.table)
require(reshape2)
library(glue)

data_13_Sam  <- data.frame(
  Ratings = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), flag = c("Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","Yes")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(offset = 0, width = 1,uiOutput("rat")),
  column(offset = 0, width = 2, uiOutput("nt"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  filter_data <- reactive({
    data_13_Sam %>% filter(flag %in% input$nt, Ratings %in% input$rat)
  })
  

  
  ##### nt
  


    output$nt <- renderUI({
      selectInput("nt",label = tags$h4("New"),choices = unique(filter_data()$flag))
    })

  
  ###### rat
  

    output$rat <- renderUI({
      selectInput("rat",label = tags$h4("Rat"),choices = unique(filter_data()$Ratings))
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also tried with this second approach as well . But did not work. Writing to csv file and then pulling from that

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

data_13_Sam  <- data.frame(
  Ratings = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), flag = c("Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","Yes"),
  fle = c("All","All","All","All","All","All","All","All","All","All")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(offset = 0, width = 1,uiOutput("all")),
  column(offset = 0, width = 1,uiOutput("rat")),
  column(offset = 0, width = 2, uiOutput("nt")),
  tableOutput('data')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  
  observeEvent(input$rat,{
    grp_by <- data_13_Sam %>% filter(Ratings %in% input$rat) %>% group_by(flag) %>% summarise(Det= n())
    write.csv(grp_by,"grp_by.csv")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$nt,{
    grp_by_nt <- data_13_Sam %>% filter(flag %in% input$nt) %>% group_by(Ratings) %>% summarise(Det= n())
    write.csv(grp_by_nt,"grp_by_nt.csv")
  })
  
  output$rat <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(input$nt)){grp_by_nt_read <- read_csv("grp_by_nt.csv")}
    selectInput("rat",label = tags$h4("Rat"),choices = unique(grp_by_nt_read$Ratings))
  })
  
  output$nt <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(input$rat)){grp_by_read <- read_csv("grp_by.csv")}
    selectInput("nt",label = tags$h4("New"),choices = unique(grp_by_read$flag))
  })

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `filter_data()` is dependent on `input$nt` and `input$rat`. `selectInput(“nt”)` and `selectInput(“rat”)` are dependent on `filter_data()`. You are doing a circular reference. You might need to review what you intend to do.

Comment: Yes. What I need was the filter should be reactive to each other. For example, if I select 5 under "Rat" , then filter in "New" should be only "Yes" since 5 has only Yes

Comment: For what you want to achieve, having one reactive filter for each selectInput might be appropriate.

Comment: Can we not make it reactive to each other. In my edited question, 5 does not have "No", So when we select "No" under "New", the other filter should not have 5. Also when we select 5 under "Rat", the other filter should not have "No". Make sense ?:)

Comment: Or, change `%>% filter(… , …)` to `%>% filter(… | …)`. OR instead of AND.

Comment: I tried with this as well. Does not work

Answer (score 1):

You have created a circular dependency. A needs B, B needs C but C needs A. So it is not able to complete anything.

You can try this -

```
library(shiny)

data_13_Sam  <- data.frame(
  Ratings = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), flag = c("Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","Yes","No")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(offset = 0, width = 1,uiOutput("rat")),
  column(offset = 0, width = 2, uiOutput("nt")),
  tableOutput('data')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  filter_data <- reactive({
    data_13_Sam %>% filter(flag %in% input$nt, Ratings %in% input$rat)
  })
  

  output$rat <- renderUI({
    selectInput("rat",label = tags$h4("Rat"),choices = unique(data_13_Sam$Ratings))
  })
  
  
  output$nt <- renderUI({
    req(input$rat)
    selectInput("nt",label = tags$h4("New"),choices = unique(data_13_Sam$flag[data_13_Sam$Ratings == input$rat]))
  })
  
  output$data <- renderTable({filter_data()})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So `rat` displays all the ratings and only for those ratings we display the `nt` values. You can also reverse this condition if needed to show all values of `nt` and based on it's selection show `rat` values.

Comment: Can we not make it reactive to each other. In my edited question, 5 does not have "No", So when we select "No" under "New", the other filter should not have 5. Can we achieve this?

Comment: You should have dependency only one way and not have them circular. Right now, `nt` is dependent on `rat` input. You can change that to have `rat` dependent to `nt` but you should not have `rat` dependent on `nt` and `nt` dependent on `rat`. That will not work and both the inputs would just wait for other one. That is why you see no dropdown values in your code.

Comment: even i thought so. So asked a question here if there is a way to do. But are you sure we cannot achieve this?

Comment: Yes, as far as I am aware.

Comment: Thanks. Any other r shiny experts here you can solve this problem? Please help me :)

Comment: just tried around. Looks like this is not possible.

Comment: I also tried with the second approach (see edited question) where it is not depending on 2 filters. But still not working